# Docker compose knex script error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, knex.js

My docker compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    image: myimage
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=region
      - NODE_ENV=development
    command: bash -c "sleep 10 && npm run knex migrate:latest --knexfile src/knexfile.js"
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb

    volumes: 
        - /var/lib
```

The idea is that when i do a docker-compose up it spins up mysql and the does the linking as well, my requirement is that when myImage is spinning up there is some knex migration i want to executed.
Tried 2 ways:

1. Added Command in the docker compose file as shown above.
2. Without command spin up the container and then bash to the container and try running the knex migrate command.

The application image has a dependency for knex in package json file and i can see knex module present in the node modules directory as well.

However in either case i get an error for missing knex script:

```
npm ERR! missing script: knex
```

Any suggestions on above are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Are you in correct directory with your package.json when running it?

`npm run missing-script` gives an error `npm ERR! missing script: missing-script`, if the script doesn't exist.

#### Do you have knex script in your package.json ?

```
scripts: {
  knex: "knex"
}
```

#### Have you run `npm install` before trying to run migrations?

Probably not this one, but might be necessary if `knex` script is found correctly from package.json

#### You might need to add -- for being able to pass parameters to npm run script

```
npm run knex -- migrate:latest --knexfile src/knexfile.js
```

Comment: the dependencies were installed as a part of the docker build, alternatively i bashed the container and tried to do the npm install there as well but that would not allow me to do that, when all the other dependencies are installed what could be the reason that knex isnt installed.

Comment: I updated the answer, my first though was clearly wrong :)

Comment: :) no luck however:
1. scripts did not have "knex":"knex" in package.json which i added and then tried again.
2. also tried: command: bash -c "sleep 10 && npm run knex -- migrate:latest --knexfile src/knexfile.js"
3. I am in the application directory where i run the same knex command when i run it without docker....

Comment: The error though says: 

web_1  | sh: 1: knex: not found
web_1  | npm info lifecycle image@1.0.0~knex: Failed to exec knex script

Comment: found the problem actually the environment was not getting set properly and hence the dependency was not getting picked but suprisingly it is now trying to install mysql using npm install mysql:
Working directory changed to /app/src
web_1  | Using environment: development
web_1  | Knex: run
web_1  | $ npm install mysql --save
web_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
web_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
web_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:517:17)

Answer (score 0):

You must have `knex` installed:
``bash
npm install knex

````
Must have the script defined in the `package.json`:
```json
"scripts": {
  "knex": "node --no-warnings --loader tsx ./node_modules/.bin/knex",
},
````